# Ways of loading bitmap/drawable to view async in android

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, loading, drawable

I've got activity that has to do many things before it is visible. In proccess of loading view I have to load up bitmap/drawable that consume some time and prevents from other actions that could be done in that time. So i decide to move it to another thread. I've used Async Task, but this is not solid way of loading things. There are situations where task starts 1-2 sec after my view is shown! Is there anothe way to load bitmap/drawable that will not consume so much time and will allow to assign it to ImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you are still blocking your UI thread before executing the task. Use a logger to verify when your task is being executed.

If the task *does* take up a lot of time to execute then the bitmaps you are loading may be too large, in which case you should look at the down-sampling the images you are loading using   the `inSampleSize` option with `BitmapFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` runs tasks from a thread pool which might already be fully in use so it might have to keep the tasks in queue until a thread frees up to run new task. Though I doubt this is the cause of the problem.

You should maybe consider displaying a progress indicator before the actual view you want to show to make sure all tasks are done before the user sees them.

**Edit**

you could also use task.get(); after running all the other tasks to wait for the bitmap loader to complete before showing anything... but do try to keep the UI responding!